# How to get around the error when using Spread to make an object copy where the object class has abstract methods?

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax

In the following code, I have an abstract class, which requires extended classes to implement an abstract method. When using "spread" syntax, it complains about the implementation of the abstract method is missing.

```
abstract class Test {
    abstract func(): void;
}

class Test1 extends Test {
    func(): void {}
}

function funcTest(): void {
    const test1: Test = new Test1();
    const test: Test = {...test1};
}
```

How do you use spread to make a copy of an object of class with abstract methods? If can't, is there a way around it?

Here is the example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zuryyw

Comment: This is a typescript question not an angular question right?

Comment: I dont think this has to do with spread. The line before spread where you do `new Test();` is already illegal since you cant instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: @chiliNUT it was just a typo. It creates an instance of Test1, then use spread to copy and cast to Test.

Comment: @DaleBurrell added typescript to the tags. I came from angular world, never knew it was part of typescript. Thanks.

Comment: Line 2 is still trying to create an instance of Test, which isn't possible as per my answer.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I gave you an example. It is totally valid code.

Comment: Then what is your question? In your question you say you are getting an error? Now you say its working?

Comment: @DaleBurrell check the example first. I commented out the line that caused error in my question. Uncomment it to see the error.

Comment: OK see my answer now.

Comment: You might want to edit your question then, because your question says "How do you use spread" whereas your recent comment implies you're interested in any solution.

Comment: How did you solve it in the end?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I didn't. I avoided it. Still hoping for a workable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition you can't create an instance of an abstract class - no matter which mechanism you use.

*EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS*

Spread will create a new object, it won't be of type `Test`, so the assignment to a variable of type `Test` will be based on it having the same properties and methods.

You can accomplish that when you remove `func` from `Test`, but you can't when its there because the object created by spread doesn't have all the properties and methods of `Test`.

Comment: Nor which language

Comment: Sorry just a typo. It creates an instance of Test1, then use spread to copy and cast to Test.

Comment: Line 2 is still trying to create an instance of Test, which isn't possible.

Comment: @DaleBurrell no, it is totally valid. Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zuryyw

Comment: I think the most important thing to mention is that TypeScript fails this _by design_ because the spread syntax does not copy non-enumerable properties like class instance methods.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - you're totally right - you should add that as a separate answer.

Comment: Yes I understand why the error, I want to know also whats the way around it? Object assign? Copy constructor? Passing function as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign will do a shallow copy of own properties and methods so should do the trick here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

However if your real-life code is more complex it may require a combination of approaches. I suggest a google of copying objects in javascript.

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript